# Parsing json array with no name in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a Json Array as string with no name and I want to parse it 
how can i do it in android ?

My JsonArray is :

```
  [
  { 
    "categoryId":1,
    "Title":"Rock",
    "songs":null
  },
    { 
    "categoryId":2,
    "Title":"Jaz",
    "songs":null
    }
  ]
```

Comment: what you tried, so far ?

Comment: for Json parser which class you are using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

       JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

      System.out.println("categoryId : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("categoryId"));
       System.out.println("Title : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("Title"));
       System.out.println("songs : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("songs"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
JSONArray a = new JSONArray(myJsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

     String title = obj.getString("Title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do like this**

```
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jsonString);

for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
    Syste.out.println("Object : " + i + " = " + jArr.getJSONObject(i));
}
```