# Parse json array from file without name

Tags: json, arrays

I know how to parse a json array when it has a name. But I am confused as to how it is done when the array does not have a specified name. I tried following the following example on stackoverflow.

[Parsing json array with no name in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416585/parsing-json-array-with-no-name-in-android)

But I did not follow what was being passed into the following line of code from the above thread.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);
```

Plus since I am a newbie, I cannot post comments and ask the user who gave the answer. Which is why I am posting the question here. Can somebody please guide me the right direction?

ReadJson.java

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class ReadDiffJson {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
    Object object = jp.parse(new FileReader("file1.json"));

    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) object;
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jo);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println("ID : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("id"));
        System.out.println("Name : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("name"));
    }
    }
}
```

file1.json

```
[
{ 
 "id":1,
 "name":"John", 
},
{ 
"id":2,
 "name":"Bob",

  }
]
```

Comment: What do you see in the jsonarray?

Comment: jo has toJsonArray method. You can try that.

Comment: do you mean something like this?                           JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) object;
String str = jo.toJSONString();
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(str); //this line gives error

Comment: Is there anything else you can suggest Zues? I am really lost here :(

Comment: I meant, jo.toJsonArray()