# Parse JSONArray with no name using Volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to figure out how to parse this JSON array that has no name. I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416585/parsing-json-array-with-no-name-in-android) but i'm trying to use the Volley library to parse my data.

```
 [
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "employee":1,
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "employee":2,
    },
    {
        "name": "name3",
        "employee":3,
    }   
    ]
```

The java code I have now is

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try{
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(???);

                        for(int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject contact = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String name = contact.getString("name");
                            int employee_ID = contact.getInt("employee");

                            }
                            textView.append(name + employee_ID );
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLY", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
```

I'm not sure what to put for the parameters of response.getJSONArray() since my array has no title.

Comment: I think you need to review the JSON format. There are JSON objects and there are JSON arrays. There are no _JSON array that has no name_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Would this be just one big JSON object then? Sorry, i'm really new and I'm not sure where to look for these things. If you could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: No, this is a JSON array, plain and simple. See [here](http://www.json.org).

Comment: so, if this is JSON array, so where is the name of it?